# Perl в php

Tags: php, perl

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, у меня есть скрипт на perl. Вот его часть:

```
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq POST)
{
    print "content-type: application/octet-stream\n\n";

    read(STDIN, $in, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

    (my$info, my$data) = split(/data=/, $in);
    @args = split(/\|/, $info);
    my$cmd;
    my$name;
    my$size;
    my$port;
    my$param;
    my$win;
```

Мне нужно его аналог на php, но perl мне не понятен. Из всего кода, что я смог перевести на php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

print $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];

}
```

выводит число 629 которое я не знаю даже от куда не похоже не одно из приблизительных значений которые должны были придти 
примерно вот что на оригинале приходит

```
cmd=enter|port=10000|name=Lecome|param=006000000F5|win=0
```

Мне хотелось бы аналог на php вот эту строку или же направление, в какую сторону искать

```
read(STDIN, $in, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
```

С остальным думаю разберусь.

Comment: Строго говоря, код на перле ужасен и хорошо демонстрирует как делать не надо. Идея самостоятельно разбирать данные POST плоха для любого языка, для PHP тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша интерпретация кода неверная. Печатать `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` не нужно. Поток входных данных, отправленных методом POST, читается так

```
$in = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

или так

```
$in = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
```

Смотрите "[дескрипторы потоков](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php)" в мануалах PHP, про `php://input` - там есть объяснение некоторых технических моментов.